# Weird Logo at bottom

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design

I was reviewing the close votes and meanwhile, I saw the following where the Stack Overflow logo is popping out of the footer at the left bottom and remains there even if you scroll up or down.

#### System Info

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
- Mozilla Firefox Quantum 64-bit

See the image below for reference:

[image]

Comment: What browser? What platform? Do you have any active scripts running?

Comment: @Werner i added the System Info and no I don't have any active scripts running and it shows up on the review section only not on the question or anywhere else.